# Symfony 5.4 detect autmatically the entity properties have changed with doctrine.orm.entity_listener

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, event-listener

I have created an event listener to send email if entity name has updated.
My question is, I’d like know what properties have changed (e.g), $entity->getName() = “Jim” became “Jimmy” ?

/!\ I'll detect only changed properties.

```php
public function postUpdate(Entity $entity, LifecycleEventArgs $event): void {
    // “Jim”


    // Now is “Jimmy”

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think it would better to use a preUpdateEvent in your case.

`Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs` contains a few method that would help your in your use case.

For example hasChangedField, getNewValue and getOldValue.

```
/**
 * Checks if field has a changeset.
 *
 * @param string $field
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasChangedField($field)
{
    return isset($this->entityChangeSet[$field]);
}
```

So you could replace your postUpdate listener with a preUpdate listener:

```
public function preUpdate(Entity $entity, PreUpdateEventArgs $args): void {
    if($args->hasChangedField('name')){
        $newName = $args->getNewValue('name');
        $oldName = $args->getOldValue('name');
    }

}
```

Otherwise if you want to keep your postUpdate listener, you will need use the unit of work to find your entity changeset and see if the name field has changed.

Comment: Quick hint: You can even flag if something has changed in preUpdate via a class variable and actually update the change in postUpdate. This prevents to update something that wasn't changed due to a database error or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$event->get(Entity|Object)Manager()->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityChangeSet($entity)
```

Comment: Thanks @hazadam, it work for me with $args->getObjectManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityChangeSet($entity)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. `$event->get(Entity|Object)Manager()`  does not look like valid PHP code to me